# Troble with Nodes in HTML (hierarchyRequestError)

Tags: javascript

I get an error message when I use the following code, I've looked at similar questions they all say that I must be trying to insert an element node where it can't go, but I can't see what I've done wrong.

```
function cutSelect(){
$.each(fibre, function(i, carpet){
    if(carpet.weave == 'Cut'){
        pile.push(carpet);
    }
});
document.getElementById("weaveSelect").style.display = "none";
$.each(pile, function(i, carpet){
    place = document.getElementById("displayDiv");
    imgLink = document.createElement("a");
    img = document.createElement("img");
    br = document.createElement("br");
    name = document.createElement("a");
    price = document.createElement("p");
    extra = document.createElement("p");
    imgLink.href = carpet.link;
    img.src = carpet.photo;
    img.style.width = "300px";
    img.style.height = "300px";
    img.style.padding = "20px, 20px, 10px, 20px";
    imgLink.appendChild(img);
    name.href = carpet.link;
    name.innerHTML = carpet.name;
    price.innerHTML = "£" + carpet.price + "m2";
    extra.innerHTML = carpet.extra;
    place.appendChild(imgLink);
    place.appendChild(br);
    place.appendChild(name);
    place.appendChild(price);
    place.appendChild(extra);   
});
}
```

Hopefully someone can shed some light on the issue.

Comment: Just by looking at it, I'd at least suggest using the `var` keyword every now and then ?

Comment: Can you provide a working example (like [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: no actually adding the var at the beginning fixed it, I got lazy or overconfidant, thanks though.